# Unit test for RxJava subject in ViewModel

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, rx-java2

For example, I created an example code that needs to be tested

```
class MyViewModel() : BaseViewModel() {

    private val valueSubject = BehaviorSubject.create<String>()

    private val viewState = MutableLiveData<State>()
    fun getViewState(): LiveData<State> = viewState

    init {
        disposables.add(valueSubject
                .debounce(150L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) //problem
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe {
                    viewState.value = State(it)
                })
    }

    fun valueChanged(value: String) {
        viewState.value = State(value + " processing")
        valueSubject.onNext(value)
    }
}
```

For example, you need to write a text that, with `valueChanged ("12")`, would catch 2 `viewState` changes, the first change is `viewState.value = State (value + "processing")`, and the second is already in the valueSubject subscription.

The problem as I understood it here in `debounce(150L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)`, there are such solution [examples](https://medium.com/@grzesiek.matyszczak/how-to-test-debounce-in-rxjava-2-d43f64b5d58a), but is it possible somehow without throwing the sheduller?

Basic part of the test

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class Test {

    @get:Rule
    var rule: TestRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
        RxJavaPlugins.onComputationScheduler(Schedulers.trampoline())
        RxJavaPlugins.setNewThreadSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
        RxJavaPlugins.setIoSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've already found out by yourself, moving the scheduler's clock forward is the way to go when dealing with all sorts of "delay" operators (such as delay, interval, timer and in your case debounce).

To help you out in the setup process, you could use a custom rule class and directly trigger your scheduler's events.

```
class RxTestSchedulerRule : Rule {

    lateinit var testScheduler: TestScheduler

    override fun onBefore() {
        testScheduler = TestScheduler()
        RxJavaPlugins.setIoSchedulerHandler { testScheduler }
        RxJavaPlugins.setComputationSchedulerHandler { testScheduler }
        RxJavaPlugins.setNewThreadSchedulerHandler { testScheduler }
        RxJavaPlugins.setSingleSchedulerHandler { testScheduler }
        RxAndroidPlugins.setMainThreadSchedulerHandler { testScheduler }
        RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler { testScheduler }
    }

    override fun onAfter() {
        RxJavaPlugins.reset()
        RxAndroidPlugins.reset()
    }
}

fun CompositeRules.testScheduler() = getRule<RxTestSchedulerRule>().testScheduler
fun CompositeRules.advanceTimeBy(duration: Long, unit: TimeUnit) = getRule<RxTestSchedulerRule>().testScheduler.advanceTimeBy(duration, unit)
fun CompositeRules.advanceTimeTo(duration: Long, unit: TimeUnit) = getRule<RxTestSchedulerRule>().testScheduler.advanceTimeTo(duration, unit)
fun CompositeRules.triggerActions() = getRule<RxTestSchedulerRule>().testScheduler.triggerActions()
```

Then in your test class can be simplified with this

````
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class Test {

    @get:Rule
    var rule: TestRule = RxTestSchedulerRule()

    @Test
    fun `test view state correctly handled`() {
       // Setup your stream

       advanceTimeBy(150L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)

       // Assert obs has emitted view state
    }

}
```
````